# onDeleteComplete return false but preview image is gone

Tags: fine-uploader

I have a question.
I want to delete image, but if there is sobe error on backend I return sussess:false. But on breakpoint of event onDeleteComplete I see that preview image is always removed from list of thumnail images.
How to prevent remove preview image?

I see that on event onDelete is preview image deleted, but on this event is not any information about backend processes.

I talk about session images. I have defined deleteFileEndpoint which return success:false, but image in preview is gone.

And I see that it is same with fresh uploaded file. In endpoint.php I will hardcoded $result = array("success" => false, "uuid" => '');, soo I expecting to leave image in preview, because is not deleted!

By me is more correct when preview image is deleted after success=true and not before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to delete image, but if there is sobe error on backend I return sussess:false

I assume you mean a JSON response containing `"success": false`. This is the problem. If you want to declare a delete request to be a failure, you must set the response code appropriately (i.e. 4xx or 5xx). This is explained in the [delete feature documentation](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/features/delete.html).